# Reformat Json response using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object that I cannot control the feed of.  The feed sends one object with an undifined array of objects with in it.  I need each object to be defined at an asset to the asset with all its attribute (path, name, title, etc) with in each object with in assets like the second result below.  If there is a functiond idea or a jquery pluggin that can help.  Can some one help me get this result please.

Edit: 
I had to remove the json object for privacy reasons.  Thank you to those that responded.

Comment: what have you tried? why didn't it work? who controls the original format? why not change it there?

Comment: JSON is still Javascript. You can manipulate it on-the-fly and reformat it without a plugin. However, it's totally unclear to me what exactly changed/how you want it to be changed. Please narrow this question down a little.

Comment: @PaulEngstler, your response was all the information that I needed to think a little further into this and solve the issue.

Comment: If it really needs to be private, you should delete this question as it is still available in the edit history. You might want to then repost the question with a version of the JSON that is scrubbed of the "private" info.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the JSON array and rearrange the elements into an output array

```
var json = { "assets": [ ... ] };
var out = [];
for (var i in json.assets) {
    var v = json.assets[i];
    v.id = +i + 1;
    v.title_id = +i + 1;
    out.push({ 'asset': v });
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TnRx/4/) for testing.